# How to maintain the order of rows while export to excel

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gwt

I am using datagrid of GWT to display the data into a table and along with that I have a button called as export to excel but the problem is when I export to excel record is getting rearranged into excel file .Please help me

Comment: Where is the code you have written?

Comment: Do post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us to help

Comment: I have solved the problem actually I was using Set  which doesn't maintain the insertion order ,so in place of Set I used LinkedHashSet and it worked for me .Thank you guys